# Install odbc drive for drill

Tags: odbc

I followed these steps to config the odbc drive for drill: 
[Configuring ODBC on Linux](https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-odbc-on-linux/)

After that I try to test the drill connection according [Testing the ODBC Connection Instruction](https://drill.apache.org/docs/testing-the-odbc-connection/#testing-the-odbc-connection-on-linux)

```
/usr/bin/iodbctest

iODBC Demonstration program
This program shows an interactive SQL processor
Driver Manager: 03.52.0709.0909

Enter ODBC connect string (? shows list): DSN=Drill;ConnectionType=ZooKeeper;ZKQuorum=192.168.0.253:2181,192.168.0.254:2181;ZKClusterID=drillbits1
Driver: 1.2.0.1000 (MapR Drill ODBC Driver)

SQL>select columns[0] as 'Year',columns[1] as Revenues  from 'hdfs.root'.'./user/hdfs/R/DisneyFinancialTest.csv'
1:  ERROR [HY000] [MapR][Drill] (1070) Drill fails to execute the query with error [30017]Communication error. End of file
```

It works well with the connection to sql, but it shows that the drill fails to execute. What does the issue means? Can anyone help me trouble shot this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out what was the issue, the problem was that my odbc driver version and my drill version is not match. I uninstalled the drill odbc driver 1.2 and installed version 0.8, it works well.

I solved the problem by referencing [this link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-2295).

Answer (score 1):

`quit;` is interpreted as a SQL command, which is not valid for Drill. If you want to quit isql, then just use `quit`.